# robocopy /xf only checks the first three characters of the extension

Tags: robocopy

Robocopy checks only the first three characters of an extension.

Therefore, `Excel.exportedUI` is NOT BACKED UP if I specify `/xf *.exp`.

I have not heard of anyone complaining about this, so I suspect that I am either missing something, or many people are not copying the files they suspect they are.

E.g.,

Given a folder with four files,

```
    t.a
    t.ab
    t.abc
    t.abcd
```

The command,

```
    robocopy . testout /xf *.a
```

EXcludes only one file `t.a` (as expected).

```
    robocopy . TestOut /xf *.ab
```

excludes only one file, `t.ab` (as expected).

```
    robocopy . TestOut /xf *.abc
```

excludes *TWO* files: `t.abc` (as expected) *and* `t.abcd` (which is NOT expected).

Specifically including a file type, e.g.,

```
    robocopy . testout *.abcd /xf *.abc
```

copies no files at all. (Evidently, `/xf` supersedes any specified file to include.)

I also tried the `/if` option to no avail:

```
    robocopy . testout /if *.abcd /xf *.abc
    robocopy . testout /xf *.abc /if *.abcd
```

This is problematic because I am trying to copy, for example, `.exportedUI` files but NOT `.exp` files.

Am I doing something wrong, here? Is there a workaround? I would like to use robocopy because of its flexibility.

Comment: what does robocopy . Testout /xf *.abc yield?

Comment: can you use inclusion rather than exclusion,i.e. robocopy . testout *.exportedUI

Comment: This is a serious issue. This unexpected behavior makes me question how thorough my backups have been over the years. Who knows how many files with extensions longer than three characters I have failed to backup because of my rather long `/xf` list?

Comment: yes, /xf would supercede. Can you leave off the /xf, that should just give you the .abcd, you might need multiple robocopy's to get what you want; I imagine /xf must be looking at the 8.3 file extension ( run a dir /x to see those), or using flawed "starts with" instead of equal to.

Comment: Thanks, SqlACID. I am doing this for everything in the `Documents` folder, and this should be easy for others in my department to use, so multiple robocopy statements are probably a no-go. (It strikes me a weird that the developers of robocopy didn't account for non 8.3 filenames.)